# Install old python and wxpython version in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, python

I have been trying to use an app that is dependent on Python 2.5 for a while. It's no problem installing it in Ubuntu (which I use) but to then get wxpython is harder. I could'nt compile it for some reason.

Now I think I just give up and use this app in a VM. But what would be the easiest distro to use for this? Which modern distros do have old versions of python and wxpython in their repositories? Right now I install Ubuntu 9.04 but I figure it must be a better way!

Comment: What application are you trying to run?

Comment: Dabo - dabodev.com

Comment: Dabodev seems to support wxPython 2.8 (current stable). Any recent Linux distribution should have his in their repo. You can use Python 2.7.

Comment: One year ago the authors of the framework thought you should stick to python 2.6 (or even better 2.5). And I have heard problems since. But, you're right I could give it a go again...